# Stuck in a "Running machine configuration script"

Tags: cloud, lxd, juju, maas, charmed-kubernetes

Following [this bash file](https://github.com/antongisli/maas-baremetal-k8s-tutorial/blob/main/maas-setup.sh)

We are facing issue that the time i add juju bootstrap maas-controller it goes in running machine configuration script and waiting more than 2 hrs.

[image]

Resources added for juju-controller

1. 4 core CPU
2. 8Gb RAM
3. 16Gb storage